# Hazelcast on Glassfish as an OSGI bundle

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi, hazelcast

Good day. I have some difficulties using the Hazelcast in Glassfish OSGi environment.

I have an OSGi bundle, which provides some EJBs and intended to be deployed on glassfish. This bundle uses Hazelcast and imports some hazelcast packages. I don't want to embed hazelcast jar so I tried to deploy it in Glassfish prior to deploying the subj. bundle.

```
$ asadmin deploy --type=osgi minimal-json-0.9.1.jar
$ asadmin deploy --type=osgi hazelcast-3.3.3.jar
```

Hazelcast deployed successfully. But when I deploy my bundle, and when one of the EJBs from this bundle tries to create a HazelcastInstance, I get the following exception:

```
org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.DeploymentException: Deployment of xxx.xxx.platon-cache [398] failed because of following reason: Failed while deploying bundle xxx.xxx.platon-cache [398] : java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to deploy bundle [ xxx.xxx.platon-cache [398] ], root cause: Exception while loading the app
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.AbstractOSGiDeployer.deploy(AbstractOSGiDeployer.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiContainer.deploy(OSGiContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.deploy(JavaEEExtender.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.access$200(JavaEEExtender.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to deploy bundle [ xxx.xxx.platon-cache [398] ], root cause: Exception while loading the app
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.deploy(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.execute(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.AbstractOSGiDeployer.deploy(AbstractOSGiDeployer.java:123)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton HazelcastService
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.deploy(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:185)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton HazelcastService
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$000(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:81)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:654)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PortableFactory[-17] is already registered! com.hazelcast.concurrent.atomiclong.client.AtomicLongPortableHook$1@682d1719 -> com.hazelcast.concurrent.atomiclong.client.AtomicLongPortableHook$1@68479fbd
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableHookLoader.register(PortableHookLoader.java:84)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableHookLoader.load(PortableHookLoader.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableHookLoader.<init>(PortableHookLoader.java:41)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.<init>(SerializationServiceImpl.java:119)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceBuilder.build(SerializationServiceBuilder.java:175)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.createSerializationService(Node.java:195)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.<init>(Node.java:142)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:120)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:153)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:136)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:112)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at xxx.xxx.platon.cache.HazelcastService.init(HazelcastService.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1035)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:412)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:1949)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:475)
    ... 24 more
]]
```

The hazelcast instance is created in the only place, so there shouldn't be any conflicts with some other hazelcast cluster. Everything works correctly in non-osgi environment.

The hazelcast config is the simpliest one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.1.xsd" xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>
</hazelcast>
```

What is the reason of this exception?

Answer (score 1):

it smells very much like this issue: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3922.
Can you please try it with the latest [Hazelcast 3.3.4-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/hazelcast/hazelcast/3.3.4-SNAPSHOT/hazelcast-3.3.4-20141118.105809-18.jar)? It should be fixed there.

EDIT: This workaround is not needed anymore; Latest releases of both 3.3 and 3.4 branches include this fix.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I undeployed the 3.3.3 hazelcast, stopped the Glassfish domain, cleared the OSGI cache, started Glassfish and deployed the version 3.3.4-SHAPSHOT but it doesn't solve the problem - the issue remains the same. Should I do something in addition?

Comment: I also tried the workaround from the issue you provided and it works for me.